# Converting multiple x,y coordinates to new coordinate system using GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, geopandas, numpy

I have a Python script to convert the x, y coordinates in a csv file from EPSG:29902 to EPSG:2157 based on their naming Easting and Northing

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

EPSG_ITM = 2157
EPSG_Irish = 29902


# load csv file
gdf = gpd.read_file(r"file.csv")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    gdf,
    geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(
        gdf["EASTING"].astype(np.float32), gdf["NORTHING"].astype(np.float32)
    )
)
gdf.crs = f"epsg:{EPSG_Irish}"

# re-project the data
gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg=EPSG_ITM)
gdf["Easting"] = gdf["geometry"].x
gdf["Northing"] = gdf["geometry"].y

gdf.to_csv(r"newfile.csv")
```

I now have a CSV with 3 different x and y coordinate fields, so I have tried expanding the code to cope with this. However, I am getting the error:

```
TypeError: points_from_xy() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

Can anyone advise how to extend the code accordingly?

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

EPSG_ITM = 2157
EPSG_Irish = 29902


# load csv file
gdf = gpd.read_file(r"file.csv")
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    gdf,
    geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(
        gdf["M1_EASTING"].astype(np.float32), gdf["M1_NORTHING"].astype(np.float32),
        gdf["M2_EASTING"].astype(np.float32), gdf["M2_NORTHING"].astype(np.float32),
        gdf["M3_EASTING"].astype(np.float32), gdf["M3_NORTHING"].astype(np.float32)
    )
)
gdf.crs = f"epsg:{EPSG_Irish}"

# re-project the data
gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg=EPSG_ITM)
gdf["M1_EASTING"] = gdf["geometry"].x1
gdf["M1_NORTHING"] = gdf["geometry"].y1
gdf["M2_EASTING"] = gdf["geometry"].x2
gdf["M2_NORTHING"] = gdf["geometry"].y2
gdf["M3_EASTING"] = gdf["geometry"].x3
gdf["M3_NORTHING"] = gdf["geometry"].y3

gdf.to_csv(r"newfile.csv")
```

Comment: Why do you pass six coordinates to `points_from_xy`? It needs only two coordinates. What is your purpose of using six?

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I have the 3 closest AQ monitors to a town in a csv. So effectively, M1_Northing and M1_Easting are the the x and y coordinates of the closest monitor. There are also M2_Northing, M2_Easting, M3_Northing and M3_Easting. I'm trying to convert all x,y coordinates in one script

Comment: In my opinion, you have two options. (1) You can make a multipoint (three points in it) from one row (2) You can add M1, M2, M3 as separate points. That means you will get six points (six features) if you have two rows.

Answer (score 5):

Just convert to GeoSeries (geometry) and reproject them one at a time:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np

EPSG_ITM = 2157
EPSG_Irish = 29902

# load csv file
gdf = gpd.read_file(r"file.csv")

gdf["M1"] = gpd.points_from_xy(
    gdf["M1_EASTING"].astype(np.float32), gdf["M1_NORTHING"].astype(np.float32),
    crs=EPSG_Irish).to_crs(EPSG_ITM)
gdf["M2"] = gpd.points_from_xy(
    gdf["M2_EASTING"].astype(np.float32), gdf["M2_NORTHING"].astype(np.float32),
    crs=EPSG_Irish).to_crs(EPSG_ITM)
gdf["M3"] = gpd.points_from_xy(
    gdf["M3_EASTING"].astype(np.float32), gdf["M3_NORTHING"].astype(np.float32),
    crs=EPSG_Irish).to_crs(EPSG_ITM)

gdf["M1_EASTING"] = gdf["M1"].x
gdf["M1_NORTHING"] = gdf["M1"].y
gdf["M2_EASTING"] = gdf["M2"].x
gdf["M2_NORTHING"] = gdf["M2"].y
gdf["M3_EASTING"] = gdf["M3"].x
gdf["M3_NORTHING"] = gdf["M3"].y

gdf = gdf.drop(columns=["M1", "M2", "M3", "geometry"])
gdf.to_csv(r"newfile.csv")
```

Answer (score 5):

You can make a multipoint-typed GeoDataFrame using the following script.

Sample CSV:

```
M1_EASTING,M1_NORTHING,M2_EASTING,M2_NORTHING,M3_EASTING,M3_NORTHING
-361065,7600889,-361310,7600913,-361205,7600854
-361178,7600286,-361318,7600271,-361215,7600164
```

Script:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint
from pyproj import Transformer

EPSG_ITM = 2157
EPSG_Irish = 29902

# set transformation
transform = Transformer.from_crs(EPSG_Irish, EPSG_ITM).transform

gdf = gpd.read_file("file.csv")
col = gdf.columns

def set_new_coords_and_geom(row):
    x1, y1 = transform(row[col[0]], row[col[1]])
    x2, y2 = transform(row[col[2]], row[col[3]])
    x3, y3 = transform(row[col[4]], row[col[5]])
    geom = MultiPoint([[x1, y1], [x2, y2], [x3, y3]])
    
    return gpd.GeoSeries([x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, geom], index=col)

gdf[col] = gdf[col].apply(set_new_coords_and_geom, axis=1)
gdf.crs = EPSG_ITM     
gdf.to_file("file.shp")

print(gdf)

# OUT: Converted coordinates
#      M1_EASTING   M1_NORTHING    M2_EASTING   M2_NORTHING    M3_EASTING    M3_NORTHING            geometry  
# 0  38987.240879  8.099518e+06  38742.274754  8.099542e+06  38847.260744   8.099483e+06  MULTIPOINT (389... 
# 1  38874.262908  8.098915e+06  38734.282566  8.098900e+06  38837.269334   8.098793e+06  MULTIPOINT (388...
```

[image]